# how can i decompose one row to many using PDI?

Tags: sql, pentaho

My table has three columns : start_date, finish_date and segment_value

```
The segment_value contains the number of worked hours (it can be 0 as it can be 152 (random))
if (finish_date - start_date) > 7 (jours)
and we supposed that segment_value = 90, it means that we've worked 40 hours the first week (8hours by day), 40 hours the second week, and 10 the third one.

then, I need to load my table by the following :

start_date + 1 week, finih_week_date, 40
start_date + 2 week, finish_week2_date, 40
start_date + 3 week, finish_week3_date, 10
```

I want to use PDI for that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modified java script step..
Their you can write logic according to your need.